# How to modify Internet Explorer temporary internet settings with registry?

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, registry

I have been looking through registries for hours and can't seem to find the one that controls the Internet Explorer Temporary Internet File settings. I want to change from Automatic to something else.

[image]

Comment: FWIW, it's not supported to directly manipulate these registry values, and these registry settings are not guaranteed to continue to work after IE's monthly updates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
```

DWORD called **SyncMode5**

- 0 = Never
- 2 = Every time you start internet explorer
- 3 = Every visit to the page.
- 4 = Automatically

Found it [here](http://forums.citrix.com/thread.jspa?threadID=68159) - first result if you [Google "temporary internet files check for newer registry"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=temporary+internet+files+check+for+newer+registry).

Tried it out and it is certainly true for IE8/XP SP3

Comment: Ahh thanks! I had seen that listing but thought SyncMode5 was a directory not the actual register file.

Comment: @Phil I know, it took me a little while to cotton on - the main reason is that the value doesn't exist until you change it in the dialog you put in your question, it just defaults to `Automatic` and unless you've set it to something else, its not there. For future excercises like this, take a look at [RegFromApp](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/reg_file_from_application.html) - it lets you track the registry changes any process is making. Great for cracking badly written software... Not that I would ever do that, you understand...

Comment: Thanks for the helpful tip! I will definitely use that in the future.

Comment: L@@K: This REG hack DOES NOT work on Windows 7 with IE Versions 8, 9, 10 or 11. I have been fighting with this for days.. even the VB Script versions of this doesn't work either. The setting never sticks.. it always goes back to "Automatic"

Answer (score 0):

Script modification (save name.reg):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
    "SyncMode5"=dword:00000003
```