# Where is "Allow website caches and databases" checkbox Registry key?

Tags: internet-explorer, registry

I can't find this checkbox in the registry so I can have Desktop Authority write it to whatever it needs to be to be UNCHECKED.

I have perused many forums that address the changing of the flag/option on the first tab, IE this Stack article:

[How to modify Internet Explorer temporary internet settings with registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100557/how-to-modify-internet-explorer-temporary-internet-settings-with-registry)

BUTTTT What I truly want is the checkbox in this screenshot to be turned off (in the Caches and databases tab):

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further Googling did not offer anything but I went through the Registry one by one until I found the key in a spot completely different than the Internet Settings.

Key location:

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserStorage\AppCache]
"AllowWebsiteCaches"=dword:00000000

Setting that as 1 or 0 changes the checkmark within the internet settings.  Silly me, thinking the same options panel would have registry keys in the same spot!  Thanks!

Comment: There is a search feature in regedit. Even if you do not know the full name of the key you are looking for, you can still do a partial search and be successful.